# What's the most efficient way to convert a Matrix{T} of size 1*N or N*1 in Julia to a Vector{T}?

Tags: julia

What's the most efficient way to convert a Matrix{T} of size 1*N or N*1 in Julia to a Vector{T}?

For example, say I have

```
a = [1,3,5]
b = a'
```

Both `a` and `b` are of type `Array{Int,2}` (i.e. `Matrix{Int}`). What are the most efficient ways to convert `a` and `b` to type `Array{Int,1}` (i.e. `Vector{Int}`)?

One approach is:

```
a_vec = [x::Int for x in a]
b_vec = [x::Int for x in b]
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `vec()` function. It's faster than the list comprehension and scales better with number of elements ;)
For a matrix of 1000x1:

```
julia> const a = reshape([1:1000],1000,1);

julia> typeof(a)
Array{Int64,2}

julia> vec_a = [x::Int for x in a];

julia> typeof(vec_a)
Array{Int64,1}

julia> vec_aII = vec(a);

julia> typeof(vec_aII)
Array{Int64,1}
```

6.41e-6 seconds # list comprehension

**2.92e-7 seconds # vec()**

Comment: One important thing to note about both `vec` and `reshape` is that they share memory with the underlying array for performance – that's why `vec` is so much faster than a comprehension, which creates a new array object, copying content. Thus, if you change `a[1]`, `v_aII[1]` will also change and vice versa, whereas `v_a[1]` will be unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

vec() is faster

```
const a = reshape([1:1000],1000,1);
@time vec(a);
elapsed time: 6.914e-6 seconds (184 bytes allocated)
@time squeeze(a,2);
elapsed time: 1.0336e-5 seconds (248 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would tend to use `squeeze` to do this if the matrix is `1xN` or `Nx1`:

```
squeeze(ones(3, 1))
squeeze(ones(1, 3))
```

Not sure if that's more efficient than using `vec` or `reshape`.

Comment: Good, I didn't know about this function.

Comment: Seeing in the definitions, looks like squeeze has to be a little more slow than the other.

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/abstractarray.jl#L152

I do a little benchmark, and I found:

squeeze(m)           :   ( 2.97 +- 2 ) e-6 seconds

vec(m)               :   ( 2.02 +- 2 ) e-6 seconds

reshape(m,length(m)) :   ( 1.72 +- 2 ) e-6 seconds

Difference is very very small, but how one can expect by definitions, reshape(m,length(m)) is the faster option.