# julia: Using `vec` function in a notebook

Tags: julia

I was working on a notebook that uses the function `vec` to convert a `1xN` matrix to a `N`-element vector. This happened without issue, and `vec` is the recommended method for this, see [What's the most efficient way to convert a Matrix{T} of size 1*N or N*1 in Julia to a Vector{T}?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14421535)

However, I switched to another notebook and now doing the same thing now throws an error:

```
#cell:

vec1 = [1 2 3]

#cell output:

1×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3

#cell:

vec1 = vec(vec1)

#cell output:

MethodError: objects of type Vector{Int64} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[97]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1094
```

Oddly enough, doing the same thing on a terminal works fine, just as in the previous notebook:

```
julia> vec1 = [1 2 3]
1×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3

julia> vec1 = vec(vec1)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
```

I'm using julia 1.6.1 on both the notebook and the terminal. Is there some silly mistake  I'm missing here? I'm using `DelimitedFiles.readdlm` to read a vector from disk, so the output is a matrix by default. Thus, the solution is not as simple as switching from `[1 2 3]` to `[1; 2; 3]`.

Comment: This error message means that somewhere you've created a variable called `vec`, containing a vector, which overshadows the function `vec`. You could restart the REPL, or maybe reset the variable like this: `vec = Base.vec`

Comment: In Jupyter the @DNF suggestions becames to "restart the kernel"

Comment: @DNF `vec = Base.vec` did the trick. Thank you.